# Does an android phone's screen light being on or off affect network status?

Tags: android, ussd

For an android phone, does the screen being on or off affect the network status at all?

I am unable to run some network related USSD when phone light off or phone is locked.

Comment: They may come through, but you will not know until you turn the screen on, therefore this is a quantum mechanic event.  Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger's_cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't effect it. Emails come through when the screen is off.

I was running a version of CyanogenMod that disconnected the WIFI when the screen was off tho but thats a custom ROM

Comment: thanks for replying...but i am not using GPRS channel its normal ussd commands which runs through different channel.

Comment: you can mark the question as correct if you are satisfied with it

Comment: my guess is that when screens is off no outgoing (call,sms or ussd) can be made, so may be its possible that up link is disconnected until screen lights are on. "Don't have enough reputation to mark it correct"

Comment: I think your guess it incorrect. Why would they make it so the screen affects the radio? It makes no sense at all. Plus I am fairly certain the screen goes off when making a call and putting the phone to your ear.

It is more likely your activity is changing states and you didn't handle it.

Comment: Plus the phone can still receive calls and text when the screen is off